# Table headers with sort indicators

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a simple grid in angularjs that supports sorting. I can't work out how to correctly create a sort indicator for each of my columns that is then bound to the `sortoptions` on the controller, so that when they change, the sort indicator also changes.

My WIP is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZzPYY4ZTD8MvRIMWKEwP?p=preview

I'm creating the table and wrapping it in a directive, so that I can set the binding on the controller for the `onSort` and the `sortoptions`:

```
  <table>
  <tr>
    <thead columnwrap sortoptions="sortoptions" onsort="onSort">
      <th><column sortby='id'>Id</column></th>
      <th><column sortby='name'>Name</column></th>
    </thead>    
  </tr>
```

My wrapper directive is very simple and doesn't do much:

```
app.directive('columnwrap', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      sortoptions : '=',
      onsort: '='
    }

  };
});
```

My column directive is where all the magic should happen. In there, I'm tyring to get at `sortoptions`, but since that's declared on the parent directive, I'm not sure how to do that, and it all falls apart in the directive because of this.

```
app.directive('column', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      sortby: '@'
    },
    template: "<span><a ng-click='sort' href='#' ng-transclude></a>" +
    "<span ng-show='sortby == sortoptions.sortby'>" + // sortoptions does not exist, won't work
      "<span ng-switch='sortoptions.sortdir'>" + // again, no sortoptions
        "<span ng-switch-when='asc'> ▲</span>" +
        "<span ng-switch-when='desc'> ▼</span>" +
      "</span>" +
    "</span></span>",
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {

      scope.sort = function() {
        // Want to check the sortoptions of the controller
        var sortDir = "desc";
        if (sortoptions.sortBy == attrs.sortby) {
          sortDir = sortoptions.sortBy == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
        }
        scope.$parent.onsort(scope.sortby, sortDir)
      }
    }
  };
});
```

How can I access the sortoptions from the column directive, and have it so that when the sort column is clicked, all the column indicators update appropriately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [orderBy](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy) filter which is pretty simple and takes a predicate (to sort on) and an order (as sort order).

Docs already has an example. The example is self explanatory which I implemented it recently and if you need I can fiddle it for you, if there is still a gray area.

ng-enjoy

Comment: I don't think that's much use for me. The sorting will be done server-side, so this helper isn't much good for me. PLus my sort indicator is a toggler between asc and desc