# AngularJS - Directive does not obtain controller data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

need some help on angular.
i have a directive and i want to get the controller on the link function:

```
 link : function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
//DO Something
}
```

apparently it is an easy task, and it does work if i predefined the "ng-model" like here :

```
<numric ng-model="data.mytext" />
```

but i want to use `numric` as an attribute and to get the model from it:

```
<div numric ="data.mytext" ></div>
```

and now when i get to the link function `ctrl` is null.
my code:

```
 <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular JS demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="firsttimeCtrl">
    <div numric="data.mytext" />
</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var myapp=angular.module('myApp',[]);

myapp.controller('firsttimeCtrl',function ($scope) {
       //$scope.data=Data;

    });


myapp.directive('numric', function() {
  return {    
    require: '?ngModel',
    replace: true,

    link:function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

      function numricAddCommas(text){
      var str = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');//allowing only numbers
        var parts = (str + "").split("."),
            main = parts[0],
            len = main.length,
            output = "",
            i = len - 1;

        while(i >= 0) {
            output = main.charAt(i) + output;
            if ((len - i) % 3 === 0 && i > 0) {
                output = "," + output;
            }
            --i;
        }
        // put decimal part back
        if (parts.length > 1) {
            output += "." + parts[1];
        }
        if(output !== text) {
            str=output;
            ctrl.$setViewValue(output);
            ctrl.$render();
        }
        return output;

    }

        ctrl.$parsers.push(numricAddCommas);
    },
    template:'<input type="text" />'


  }; 
});
</script>
</html>
```

there is a way to know what controller i'm in by using the template? or there is another way?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access controller scope from directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385543/access-controller-scope-from-directive)

Answer (score 1):

Your directive should declare a scope:

```
.directive("...",function(....){
return {
scope:{
input:"=",
},
link:function(scope,element,attrs){
//access the input as scope.input
}

};
});
```

And use it like:

```
<div directive-name input="var_name_on_scope"></div>
```

You might also want to read this question:
[What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)