# AngularJS bindings when adding DOM with element.append

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to build a "fold out" directive.
The HTML always have a title and some content. The title should always be shown, and when you push the title, the content will be shown as well.

Also the content will bind to the view controller.

Controller.js:

```
app.controller('MyController', function(...) {
     $scope.my_variable = "HELLO WORLD";
});
```

HTML:

```
<div roll-down>
        <div id="open-on" class="title">
           MY TITLE
        </div>

      <div class="content">
          {{my_variable}}    <--- controller, not directive. 
      </div>
</div>
```

RollDownDir.js:

```
app.directive('rollDown', function(...) {
    var linkFn;
    linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var title     = element[0].querySelector('.title');
      var content   = element[0].querySelector('.content');

      var content_buffer = angular.copy(content);
      content.remove();

      var addContent = function(){
          element.append(content_buffer); 
          $compile(content_buffer)(scope);
      }

      angular.element(element).on('click', function (evt) {
        addContent(); 

        $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
        $rootScope.$apply();
        scope.$apply();
      });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link: linkFn
    };
});
```

Now this works fine BUT, the binding in the controller "my_variable" will never be compiled. So it will just be empty? How can I overcome this?

I have to remove the content DOM completely for performance (it is for mobile application, and the content is heavy stuff like SVGs etc.).

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385543/access-controller-scope-from-directive

Comment: `<div roll-down my-var="my_var">`

Comment: No, unfortunately this won't help me ^.. The point is that the directive does not know anything about the content. It just makes sure to remove it, and to be able to add the content later on again.

Comment: first compile, then append. Also this directive looks like ng-if...

Comment: @PetrAveryanov But how can I control the ng-if from the directive?

Comment: you dont need this directive) Your directive, presented here, compile and add content to element -- this is exactly waht ngIf does.

Comment: I know that. I want to make this an easy re-usable directive to help me hide things and add animated roll-down effects etc. The example is simplified by removing UI part.